# Teradici PcoIP shuts down immediately after successfully logging in

Tags: vmware

Teradici PcoIP shuts down immediately after successfully logging in

Hi. I'm using the Teradici PcoIP Desktop client on Ubuntu 23.04. I haven't had this issue until as of late.

However, when I successfully log in, it just shows down. No error. Nothing.

This is the output of `journalctl -xe`:

```
Jun 21 12:27:02 onur-Z16 pcoip-client.desktop[30708]: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Jun 21 12:27:02 onur-Z16 pcoip-client.desktop[30708]: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Jun 21 12:27:02 onur-Z16 pcoip-client.desktop[30708]: X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
Jun 21 12:27:02 onur-Z16 pcoip-client.desktop[30708]:   Major opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GetWindowAttributes)
Jun 21 12:27:02 onur-Z16 pcoip-client.desktop[30708]:   Resource id in failed request:  0x6
Jun 21 12:27:02 onur-Z16 pcoip-client.desktop[30708]:   Serial number of failed request:  7
Jun 21 12:27:02 onur-Z16 pcoip-client.desktop[30708]:   Current serial number in output stream:  8
Jun 21 12:27:04 onur-Z16 pcoip-client.desktop[30708]: terminate called without an active exception
```